# HTML table (tr, td) partially ignores CSS padding

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with 2 cells and two rows.
Within these cells, there are an image. 
I have a CSS rule to remove all margin and padding inside these:

```
table, tr, td, img {
   margin:0; padding:0; /* adding !important won't change anything since no other css rules conflict with this one */
}
```

However, this doesn't work in practice. The margin is properly removed on all sides but the bottom. Illustration of the problem:
[image: Illustration]

As you can see, the td STILL has a padding below, even though the rule is active (left of illustration). I'm scratching my head here - any advice?

EDIT: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLfyD/)**

Comment: Looks like the answer is posted below.. But, do you use a css reset on your sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle;`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QLfyD/1/)

Comment: Now I understand why [html5reset](http://html5reset.org/) uses `td, td img {vertical-align: top;}` in their reset stylesheet :O (which achieves the same thing)

Answer (score 1):

Add the CSS

```
td img { display:block }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QLfyD/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add the CSS

```
 img {
      vertical-align:bottom;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I had an image and a link in the same table cell, the text in the link kept ignoring the padding and breaking out of the cell.

Turns out there was a max-width set on the image which was causing issues with the cell width calculation, removing the max-width on the image solved the issue for me.

Hopefully this might help someone else in future.